# HtmlGenericControl object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, css, htmlgenericcontrol

I'm using a pretty simple HtmlGenericControl code that just add CSS dynamically in my code behind 
and it gives me object reference not set to an instance of an object which as you see clearly not null

```
HtmlGenericControl style = new HtmlGenericControl();
     style.TagName = "style";
     style.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
     style.InnerHtml = "header{"+ imagePath +";}";
     Page.Header.Controls.Add(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

On which line does it throw the exception? Which object is the offending one? Add a breakpoint to your code and let us know. Could it be that imagePath is not set up correctly?

Update:

I just created a brand new C# WebForms project and added the following to the Page_Load method of Default.aspx.cs and then inspected the source and it does exactly what you'd expect:

```
var imagePath = "contentHere";
HtmlGenericControl style = new HtmlGenericControl();
style.TagName = "style";
style.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
style.InnerHtml = "header{" + imagePath + ";}";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(style);
```

This is added to the end of the head tag of my HTML page:

```
<style type="text/css">header{contentHere;}</style>
```

To confirm, I have the following using statements on the page:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

Comment: I tried the exact same code that you wrote copied and still it gives me the same error

Comment: In a brand new C# webforms project as I did? It definitely works for me.

Comment: well, it will be like really hard and time consuming to try to move the project to another new project, but thank you for trying to help anyway

Comment: Understood, I'm wondering if you take the code sample you supplied us and like I did, create a new project featuring just that code sample, does it work?

Comment: I've had a similar issue, but mine is due to refactoring conversion between HtmlIframe to HtmlGenericControl, for our .net Framework migration from 4 to 4.7.1. I believe in my instance it was due to something similar to lazy loading.